# How to set the title for X axis and Y axis for X-Y Scatter Plot in Excel

Tags: excel

I have a static empty chart in Excel, I have a macro which pulls the data from the excel sheet and populates the graph in the chart. Is there a way to set the title for the X axis and the Y axis using the Chart properties in excel??

Comment: Did you want a programming (VBA) answer, or a formula answer? You can like chart titles to cells without code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
Chart.Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text
```

And

```
Chart.Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text
```

Answer (score 0):

You can link the X axis and Y axis titles to cells, so that they automatically update when the cells change

Text below from this [Microsoft Article](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/link-a-chart-title-or-text-box-to-a-worksheet-cell-HP005201089.aspx)

> To easily update a chart or axis title, label, or text box that you
>   have added to a chart, you can link it to a worksheet cell by creating
>   a reference to that worksheet cell. Changes that you make to the
>   worksheet cell will automatically appear in the chart.
>
> 1. On a chart sheet or in an embedded chart, click the title, label, or text box that you want to link to a worksheet cell.
> 2. In the formula bar, type an equal sign (=).
> 3. Select the worksheet cell that contains the data or text that you want to display in the chart.
> 4. If you want to type the reference to the worksheet cell, include the sheet name followed by an exclamation point, for example,
>      Sheet1!F2
>
>    Press ENTER.